# How to compile rabbitmq-c library on Mac OS X?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm failing to compiled the `rabbitmq-c` library on Mac OS 10.6.6

I intend to build the `php-ampq` extension against it.

I've tried both the latest branch of `rabbitmq-c` and `rabbitmq-codegen` according to the [instructions here](http://code.google.com/p/php-amqp/) and the specific branches according to the [instructions here](http://php.net/manual/en/amqp.installation.php).

Running `autoreconf -i` as per instructions I get:

```
glibtoolize: Consider adding `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])' to configure.ac and
glibtoolize: rerunning libtoolize, to keep the correct libtool macros in-tree.
glibtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
configure.ac:12: installing `./config.sub'
configure.ac:12: required file `./ltmain.sh' not found
configure.ac:3: installing `./missing'
configure.ac:3: installing `./install-sh'
configure.ac:12: installing `./config.guess'
examples/Makefile.am: installing `./depcomp'
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

Running simply `autoconf` I get:

```
configure.ac:3: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.ac:12: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PROG_LIBTOOL
configure.ac:90: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_CONDITIONAL
```

Most of what I can find by searching online suggests I don't have `libtool` or `automake`. I have both.

I'm afraid I'm out of my depth with autoconf, so I don't know how/where to alter configure.ac, or whether the warning is anything do with the missing `ltmain.sh` file.

Comment: You should ask this question on the RabbitMQ Discuss mailing list.  The current maintainer for rabbitmq-c answers questions there.  Or, open up an issue on the GitHub page: https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem by installing pkg-config:

```
sudo port install pkgconfig
```